# Loading a ViewController inside a Container View

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, autolayout

I have a containerView with full screen inside a VC. If i add a child to the containerView manually from a Storyboard doing a embed segue looks fine:
[image]

But if I embed the VC by code:

```
class BannerContainerVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var container: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("test") as UIViewController
        self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
    }
}
```

I get super strange results:

[image]

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You need to tell your BannerContainer view controller that it has a new child controller, and to tell the Child that it has a parent VC.  This is described in the Apple Docs [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ImplementingaContainerViewController.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH11-SW1).  Like this:

```
   [self addChildViewController:vc];
   vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
   [self.container addSubview:vc.view];
   [vc didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Or in Swift:

```
    self.addChildViewController(vc)
    vc.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.container.frame.size.width, self.container.frame.size.height);
    self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
    vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

This ensures that various layout and touch methods are passed through to the child VC; I suspect the layout problems you have may be due to those methods not currently being called.

Comment: Indeed it fixes my constraint issues on the chield view

Comment: how to remove a viewController from a containerView in swift? because Once I add a viewController , and then another , the first one is still embedded?

Comment: See "Removing a Child View Controller" in the link embedded in my answer.  Essentially you just need to reverse the process: call `willMoveToParentViewController` on the child, remove the view, then call `removeFromParentViewController`. @AymenBRomdhane

Comment: I found this solution , but I didn't know how to use it.



func hideContentController(content: UIViewController) {
    content.willMoveToParentViewController(nil)
    content.view.removeFromSuperview()
    content.removeFromParentViewController()
}

Comment: It's difficult to help without more information - which is best put in a new question, rather than comments. Add a link here and I'll take a look.

Answer (score 10):

Tried to use the answer above but it turns out `CGRectMake` isn't available anymore.

**Updated for Swift 3**:

```
self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.container.frame.size.width, height: self.container.frame.size.height)
self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: and vc.didMoveToParentViewController(self) is now vc.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

Comment: @LuizDias Does this allow for dynamic height of the Container View?

Comment: Yes, @ethanfox27. But you need to provide the correct frame sizes at `self.container.frame.size.width` and `self.container.frame.size.height`

Answer (score 2):

Update for Swift 4.2/5.

```
let listVc = ListViewController() 
listVc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.listView.frame.width, height: self.listView.frame.height)
addChild(listVc)
listVc.didMove(toParent: self)
```

ListViewController is another view controller to be embedded.

Answer (score 1):

Just call this function: -

```
private func addChildView(viewController: UIViewController, in view: UIView) {
    viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight, .flexibleWidth]
    viewController.view.frame = view.bounds
    addChild(viewController)
    view.addSubview(viewController.view)
    viewController.didMove(toParent: self)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5.0 
Use this functions to add and remove child VC:

```
private func add(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController, childFrame:CGRect) {
        // Add Child View Controller
        addChild(viewController)

        // Add Child View as Subview
        view.addSubview(viewController.view)

        // Configure Child View
        viewController.view.frame = childFrame
        viewController.view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.didMove(toParent: self)

    }
    private func remove(asChildViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.willMove(toParent: nil)

        // Remove Child View From Superview
        viewController.view.removeFromSuperview()

        // Notify Child View Controller
        viewController.removeFromParent()
    }
```

adopted from [here](https://cocoacasts.com/managing-view-controllers-with-container-view-controllers/)

Answer (score -4):

**Updated for Swift 4**

```
self.addChildViewController(vc)
vc.view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.container.frame.size.width, height: self.container.frame.size.height)
self.container.addSubview(vc.view)
vc.didMovestrong text(self)
```