# ViewController as subview on xib view. UITableView from viewController disappears

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, addsubview

I have a storyboard with a viewController that holds a tableView. The tableview works and should populate the cells correctly.

I am able to have this viewController as a subview on an xib UIView. From the viewController my label and background is showing, but not the tableView or any cells. I have set the constraints and tried numerous sizeToFit, different view sizes, sizes on tableView, etc.

I am able to see the tableview for a small second before it disappears (to the left I think). I´m guessing it would have something to do with constraints, but I've had Xcode set all the constraints and it looks good when i'm looking at it from the storyboard.

Code for adding the subview:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vcName = "uiViewtable"

    let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("\(vcName)") as UIViewController

    let subView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.size.width , height: self.view.frame.size.height))
    subView.addSubview(vc.view)

    self.view.addSubview(subView)
    self.view.bringSubviewToFront(subView)
```

Any ideas on why this is happening?

Edit:
To clarify something: My viewController consists of a background, label and a UITableView with cells being populated. The tableView works(tested!). The subview displays perfectly except of the tableView on displaying. It seems like it is disappearing.

Comment: Maybe you should bringSubviewToFront:.

Comment: Didn't make any difference. The subview aka viewController consists of a label, background and a UITableview. The tableView does work so it has nothing to do with that not working. The label is displayed and the background like it is suppose but the tableView is disappearing.

Comment: I suspect your view controller (`vc`), and its table view, are being deallocated as soon as that code snippet completes.  You need to tell your view controller that it has a child view controller, and vice versa.  See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28852897/3985749).