# Swift UITableView does not show up the content

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, viewcontroller

I have a side menu and for each selection I want to load a new ViewController (basically each page has a separate ViewController).

This is the relevant code where I load a new ViewController:

```
    viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "commissionsViewController")

    var viewInAction = UIView()

    viewInAction = viewController.view

    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.tapOnView))

    viewInAction.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

    viewInAction.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor

    viewInAction.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false


    if let subview = containerView.viewWithTag(100) {
        subview.removeFromSuperview()
    }


    containerView.insertSubview(viewInAction, belowSubview: menuView)

    setConstrainsOnView(viewObject: viewInAction)
```

This is the code for the ViewController that is loaded:

```
import UIKit

class CommissionsViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var tableView = UITableView()
var tableData = ["Beach", "Clubs", "Chill", "Dance"]

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "my")

    tableView.contentInset.top = 20

    let contentSize = self.tableView.contentSize
    let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      y: self.tableView.frame.origin.y + contentSize.height,
                                      width: self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      height: self.tableView.frame.height - self.tableView.contentSize.height))

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer


    view.addSubview(tableView)

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my", for: indexPath)
    cell.textLabel?.text = "This is row \(tableData[indexPath.row])"

    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return tableData.count
}
```

**The problem:** As you can see the CommissionsViewController contains a tableView that is added programatically. That tableView does not show up any cell! Basically the method **cellForRowAt** is never called! And I don't understand why!

I can see a blue view, which is the tableView's background, so the tableView is in place, but it doesn't load the cells!

The method **numberOfRowsInSection** is called.

I tried to debug it using the debugger but no result. I simply don't understand the flow.

Thank you respectfully.

Comment: In the code you posted you're not calling the numberofsections function

Comment: I tried that but no result. I returned 1 and the behaviour is the same.

Comment: I tried your code and the table view loads correctly, try to call tableview.reloadData() in a viewWillAppear function.

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru in Swift 4 / Xcode 9, you don't absolutely need to call `numberOfSections`... If it's not present, it's defaulted to return `1`.

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru: wow, thanks! I will follow your advice with the viewWillAppear

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru: nope, it doesn't work. There must be something else

Comment: the viewWillAppear gets called but the data is still no visible

Comment: can you try to define the tableData array right after you instantiate the view controller? I mean in the view controller where you load the tableviewcontroller from

Comment: Why should I do that? Because the tableData array may not be instantiated correctly or at the right time? I even tried to return 10 in numberOfRowsInSection method and it should call the cellForRowAt 10 times, right? What other causes ca lead to not calling the cellForRowAt function?

Comment: I think it's a datasource issue, if you run your viewcontroller code in a separate viewcontroller you'll see that it works just fine. That's why I asked if you tried to set the array data right after instantiating.

Comment: okay, I'll try that

Comment: another suggestion: try using: self.addChildViewController(viewController) instead of: containerView.insertSubview(viewInAction, belowSubview: menuView)

Comment: I can't do that because as you can see I have a containerView where I keep all my views one by one. I realise now that I only keep the views in that containerView and I also should keep the viewControllers somehow.

If I do as you say I won't be able to slide the menu.

Comment: I tried to load the ViewController separately and it works. So the problem is when I load it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add another viewController's view to your view hierarchy, you must tell both viewControllers (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852897/3985749) for further information).

Add the `addChildViewController` and `didMoveToParentViewController` calls like this:

```
viewController = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "commissionsViewController")

self.addChildViewController(viewController)
var viewInAction = viewController.view
let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action:  #selector(self.tapOnView))
viewInAction.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
viewInAction.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0.0, green: 0.0, blue: 0.0, alpha: 0.0).cgColor
viewInAction.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
if let subview = containerView.viewWithTag(100) {
    subview.removeFromSuperview()
}
containerView.insertSubview(viewInAction, belowSubview: menuView)
setConstrainsOnView(viewObject: viewInAction)
viewController.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
```

Comment: Thank you respectfully for your answer. I will check it this evening.

Comment: Man, you are awesome! Your solution sovled my problem. It works like a charm! You got the bounty + correct answer + upvote. Keep up the good work and thank you respectfully!

Answer (score 0):

After you set the dataSource and he delegate to self, you never make the tableView load any data. That means you need to call tableView.reloadData() at the end of viewDidLoad()

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    tableView = UITableView(frame: self.view.bounds, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "my")

    tableView.contentInset.top = 20

    let contentSize = self.tableView.contentSize
    let footer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.tableView.frame.origin.x,
                                      y: self.tableView.frame.origin.y + contentSize.height,
                                      width: self.tableView.frame.size.width,
                                      height: self.tableView.frame.height - self.tableView.contentSize.height))

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = footer


    view.addSubview(tableView)
    tableView.reloadData()

}
```

Comment: I already did this and it doesn't work. It's already 2 days I'm working on it and I haven't found any solution!

I think that the problem relies on the fact that I use a containerView where I add that new view (that contains the tableView). It's very annoying because I have to think again the entire architecture of the app because of that problem.

Answer (score 0):

In `viewDidLoad` method `view` is loaded but has incorrect size.
Try to change initialization of UITableView in next way

```
let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenBounds.width, height: screenBounds.height)
tableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
```

Comment: Taras Chernyshenko: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it in a few hours to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `ComissionsViewController`, `viewDidLoad()` method and add `tableView.reloadData()` right after `view.addSubview(tableView)` — it makes all your troubles disappear.

UPD: I have just made a test project where it works. I have copied the code you posted and only commented a couple of unrelated lines. The only significant difference I made is adding the line of code I mentioned above. You can download and run it to see it works :)
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B55tO8S_7Ag7VnppMk1fWlg5dWM/view

Comment: Solomiya: I already tested that and it doesn't work on my scenario (see M. Kremer's answer above). My problem is related to the fact that I use a containerView to load another view in it. However, thank you for your answer. I'll test it in a few hours to see if it solves my problem.

Comment: I have added a link to the working project above — all the code is yours except one line. I really can't see how it might not work on your side. The only case is you did not provide enough information about your situation.

Comment: Thank you for attaching the code, Solomiya. I will test it in a few hours and I'll let you know if it solves my problem.