# iOS Swift Buttons Not Responding In View

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have written a class where a view is displayed that has a `UITextView` and a couple of buttons.  Everything works except the buttons don't respond to a tap.  Below is what I think is the relevant code in my class:

```
class FullPrompt:UIViewController {
    var canceledPressedCallback:(()->()?)?=nil
    var okPressedCallback:((_ txt: String)->()?)? = nil
    var popupView = UIView()
    var field = UITextView()
    var parentView = UIView()

    func prompt(_ message:String,view: UIViewController,numberInput: Bool, callback: @escaping (_ txt: String)->()) {
        prompt(message, view: view, numberInput: numberInput, callback: callback,cancelCallback: nil,defaultText: "")
    }

    func prompt(_ prompt:String,view: UIViewController,numberInput: Bool, callback: @escaping (_ txt: String)->(), cancelCallback: (()->())?,defaultText: String) {
        canceledPressedCallback=cancelCallback
        okPressedCallback=callback

        let cancelButton=UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: y, width: 70, height: 32))
        cancelButton.setTitle("Cancel", for: .normal)
        cancelButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(cancelButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        popupView.addSubview(cancelButton)
        let okButton=UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 210, y: y, width: 70, height: 32))
        okButton.setTitle("Ok", for: .normal)
        okButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.blue, for: .normal)
        okButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(okButtonPressed(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        popupView.addSubview(okButton)
        view.view.addSubview(popupView)
    }

    func cancelButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton ) {
        popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        if canceledPressedCallback != nil {
            canceledPressedCallback!()
        }
    }

    func okButtonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        popupView.removeFromSuperview()
        okPressedCallback!(field.text)
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: None of your views have useful frames.

Comment: Not sure how you instantiate and display this VC, but you seem to be adding buttons from this VC to the calling VC's view hierarchy.  If doing this, you must invoke certain methods so that both VCs know what's going on (otherwise, for example, touches might not be recognised).  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852897/3985749) for more detail.

Comment: Strangely in my case, the buttons inside the containerView of scrollview went completely unresponsive. The issue was the containerView didn't have the Height constraint or fixed height, once added everything was back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

I got it figured out.  My mistake was adding a view property (popupView) within my class.  Since my class was a subclass of UIViewController, I needed to add my subviews to the view property of the class, not create another view.  So, basically, wherever I add adding something to popupView, I just replaced it with self.view.  They the buttons worked fine.