# cellForRowAt not being called But numberOfSection and numberOfRowsInSection is being called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit, tableview

My code:

```
//Adding Destination VC as subview in my current view's view container
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewControllerID")
         containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
        viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)

//Now implementing Table view in the destination vc

class DestinationViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

 var tableView = UITableView()
    var tableData = ["Beach", "Clubs", "Chill", "Dance"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenBounds.width, height: screenBounds.height)
        tableView = UITableView(frame: rect, style: UITableViewStyle.plain)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue

        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "my")

        view.addSubview(tableView)

        tableView.reloadData()
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = "This is row \(tableData[indexPath.row])"

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4//tableData.count
    }
}
```

If I'm Setting the destination viewController as my initial vc from storyboard then everything is working fine.But if adding as subview in container view the cellForRowAt method is not being called but numberOfSection and numberOfRowsInSection is being called.

Is there anyone having any solution ?

Comment: You need add the UITableView to your UIViewController.View

Comment: What is the swift version?

Comment: reload tableview before add to subview

Comment: Looks like you are missing `self.addChildViewController(viewController)` in your first segment of code - see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852897/3985749).

Comment: self.addChildViewController will not work for me.I'm using viewContainer to load other view controller into the first view controller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add **self.addChildViewController(viewController)** before subviewing

```
 let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
 let viewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DestinationViewControllerID")

 self.addChildViewController(viewController)
 containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
 viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that constraints are set on `UITableView`. If so, try to to set height of `UITableViewCell` manually.

Comment: This won't be the issue because the size of the UITableView won't affect the data source methods being called neither will the height of the UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

**Firstly**, you need to have a tableview in your storyboard. After creating tableView you may subview it programmatically by:

```
self.view.addSubview(tableView)
```

or add tableView in your storyboard and create an IBOutlet like this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

**Secondly**, you haven't initialized your cell, you have only dequeued a previously created cell(which, in your case has never got created). Your code should be something like this:

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my", for: indexPath) as UITableViewCell?
if cell == nil { 
  cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "my")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your table's top-bottom-left-right constant. If your table's height is 0 then cellForRow method may not be call. If you not set your table's constant properly then then it's height may become 0.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Recheck are registered reusableidentifier

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "my", for: indexPath)
```

Comment: Remove this line.         tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "my")  and try let cell = UITableViewCell()

Comment: This couldn't possible be the issue because the cellForRowAtIndex itself is not being called and that should be called even without registering a cell.

Comment: If the numberofrow was called means surely cellforrow will call. And also use Numberofsection delegate and return 1