# UITableView's cellForRowAt not being called

Tags: swift, uitableview, uikit

I'm currently facing an issue with my `UITableView`. I have set up my cells, but they are not displaying any content. I have set breakpoints and found that the `cellForRowAt` function is not being called. However, the `numberOfRowsInSection` and `heightForRowAt` functions are being executed as expected.

```
extension DetailPageViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 500
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: DetailPageTableViewCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! DetailPageTableViewCell
        print(cell.frame)
        cell.selectionStyle = .none
        // cell.contentView.layoutIfNeeded()
        cell.configure(with: selectedItemVC)
        print("configure suc")
        return cell
    }
}
```

I have checked that the data source is not empty and that the delegate and dataSource are set correctly.
I have also made sure to call `reloadData()` on `tableView`. Despite these, the `cellForRowAt` function is not being called.
I have already checked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47976897/cellforrowat-not-being-called-but-numberofsection-and-numberofrowsinsection-is-b) but it doesn't work.

Comment: Where and how are you calling reloadData?

Comment: You are probably not setting the table and datasource delegates to self.

Comment: I have resolved the issue by setting up the tableView auto constraints.

Comment: Since I guess you don't have an error saying the method isn't implemented, and that the other Datasource methods are called, the last issue I think of is that the UITableView isn't "visible", meaning it doesn't have enough frame or isn't visible on screen, so it won't call `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`. Could you ensure that the TableView has a "real frame" (not a .zero one), and is not hidden by other views with the Xcode Debug View Hierarchy( see https://www.hackingwithswift.com/read/18/5/view-debugging)

Comment: @Larme ok thanks for your instruction