# UIStoryboardSegue embed

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicontainerview

What exactly does the embedding segue in a UIView (added as a container view) in interface builder do? I'm trying to embed a ViewController programmatically because I want to choose between two different ones. I guess I set the limiting constraints of the Container View correct because when I add the child view controller with a embedding segue in the storyboard, everything works fine but as soon as I embed it with the following code, the View Controller overlaps the bottom constraint of the containerview and it messes up my layout..

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    viewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leadingAnchor),
    viewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.trailingAnchor),
    viewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor),
    viewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
])

viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28852338/loading-a-viewcontroller-inside-a-container-view

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Dinesh Balasubramanian I got the following code now which works:

```
let viewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewController")
self.containerView.addSubview(viewController.view)
self.addChildViewController(viewController)
viewController.view.frame = containerView.bounds
viewController.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: Unclear why this would be better than the code you originally provided. Autolayout is a better way to position the subview than setting its `frame` so the code in your original question is better.

Comment: Well, that depends on the notion "works". If frame of `containerView` changes, your `viewController.view` will be left behind. It would be better to be more specific about what was wrong with the original code. By the way, one thing wrong with it is that you are calling `addChildViewController` and `addSubview` in the wrong order (though I doubt that's the cause of the problem).