# NSFetchedResultsController - no delegate functions are called

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I've been searching high and low on Stack for an answer, but this I can't seem to find anything that works. The problem is simple - I have a View Controller, which has a child Table View Controller.

```
class ViewController: UIView Controller { 
    var child: UIViewController!
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext! 

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) { 
        self.managedObjectContext = context
    }

    viewDidLoad() { 
    self.child = CustomTVC(context: self.managedObjectContext)
    self.child?.view.frame = SomeFrameThatFits
    self.addChild(child!)
    self.addSubview(child!.view)

   //Targeting
   self.someButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(addHello()), for: .touchUpInside)
   }

   @objc func addHello() { 
    _ = CoreDataWriter(context: self.managedObjectContext).save()
   }
}
```

Great, awesome, neat, well done. I'm creating the `ViewController` class in the SceneDelegate, using the provided `context`.

```
SceneDelegate

...

        let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
                window.rootViewController = ViewController(context: context)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
}
```

Now, in my `ViewController` class, I have a button, `sendButton`. All this button does it add another item to my CoreData, using a separate CoreDataWriter class, written below.

```
class CoreDataWriter { 
init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
    self.managedObjectContext = context
}

func save() {
   let message = Message(context: managedObjectContext)
   message.text = "Hello World!"

     do {
            try self.managedObjectContext.save()
            return nil
       } catch let error {
            print(error.localizedDescription)
       }
    }
}
```

Now, I have **literally** [copy and pasted Apple's example code](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nsfetchedresultscontroller) into my Table View Controller class:

```
   class CustomTVC: UITableViewController, NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate {
    var managedObjectContext: NSManagedObjectContext!
    var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Message>!

    init(context: NSManagedObjectContext) {
        self.managedObjectContext = context
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "default")
         initializeFetchedResultsController()
    }


    //MARK: CoreData connections
    func initializeFetchedResultsController() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Message>(entityName: "Message")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "sent", ascending: true)
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chat.id == %@", "123454")


        fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: request, managedObjectContext: self.managedObjectContext, sectionNameKeyPath: "chat.id", cacheName: "rootCache")
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        do {
            try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
        } catch {
            fatalError("Failed to initialize FetchedResultsController: \(error)")
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "default", for: indexPath)
        // Set up the cell
        guard let object = self.fetchedResultsController?.object(at: indexPath) else {
            fatalError("Attempt to configure cell without a managed object")
        }
        //Populate the cell from the object
        cell.textLabel?.text = object.text
        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
         guard let sections = fetchedResultsController.sections else {
                   fatalError("No sections in fetchedResultsController")
               }
               let sectionInfo = sections[section]
               return sectionInfo.numberOfObjects
    }

    //MARK: More stuff for NSData

    func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        print("controller will change content")
        tableView.beginUpdates()
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange sectionInfo: NSFetchedResultsSectionInfo, atSectionIndex sectionIndex: Int, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType) {
        print("in ctronoller")
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteSections(IndexSet(integer: sectionIndex), with: .fade)
        case .move:
            break
        case .update:
            break
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {
        print("in didChange controller")
        switch type {
        case .insert:
            tableView.insertRows(at: [newIndexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .delete:
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .update:
            tableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath!], with: .fade)
        case .move:
            tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath!, to: newIndexPath!)
        @unknown default:
            fatalError()
        }
    }

    func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

In my mind, if I push the handy dandy button, the tableview should refresh with the new 'Hello World' - but I'm getting nothing. No prints, no errors. Nothing.

I've checked my context's reference from the AppDelegate context all the way down to the send button - the same address. I've checked the `fetchedResultsController` and its delegate - not nil.

I am at a total, complete, and utter loss as to what is happening. Any ideas?

Comment: This cannot be the real code because the `save()` method has no return value. And the `NSFetchedResultsController` must have a sort descriptor.

Comment: CustomTVC or ChatroomTVC?

Comment: This might be unrelated, or it might be everything. You need to tell your child view controller that it has a parent (and tell the parent that it has a child) in order for relevant lifecycle methods to be called.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28852897/3985749).

Comment: @Joakim Daniels `CustomTVC`, i removed the irrelevant code and forgot to edit the name, good catch!

Comment: @vadian the real code has a sort descriptor and, yes, the `save()` function has an extra return in there - I truncates the code to focus on the essentials but forgot to edit that, great catch

Comment: @pbasdf Added the `moveTo` just to be sure the parent and child were connected - no dice. Still no updates.

Comment: `return nil` in `save()` still doesn’t compile. And the missing sort descriptor will crash. It’s not helpful to provide incomplete code which apparently causes the issue.

Comment: Is `addHello()` called at all?

Comment: @vadian On a button tap, yes

Comment: Solved! Primarily, I'm an idiot. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else comes across this as a problem - my Fetch Request was not properly connecting (?) to CoreData. As @vadian mentioned, the `NSSortDescriptor` is **required.**

More importantly, a floating predicate I missed in commenting out was wrong; the `id` I was comparing against in the Data Structure was a UUID - However, I was using a `CVarArg` as a `String`.

When I changed the predicate to use an `argumentArray`, all problems were fixed.

So, change this:

```
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chat.id == %@", "12345")
```

To this:

```
        let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "chat.id == %@",  argumentArray: [SomeUUID])
```